# I am trying to adjust alignment in contact form 7 but unable to do so

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

[Check Image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhCqz.png) 
Link to page- [Click to visit page](https://wordpress-959727-3544033.cloudwaysapps.com/apply/)

I am trying to align the columns to left but can't do it.
Code used-

[text* username placeholder "Your Name *"][email* email placeholder "Your Email *"][select Apply-For first_as_label "Apply For" "Fire Alarm Tech" "Sprinkler Tech" "Inspector" "Other"][file attach-file][textarea* message placeholder "Your Message ..."]Submit Query

Comment: this is not a CF7 related issue as CF7 plugin does not have any layout styling css.  This alignment is coming from your overall form layout and theme styling.  If you want to create grid layouts for CF7 forms, I recommend you use a plugin like the [Smart Grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), which allows you to create such forms.